# Função SASS não funciona

Tags: html, css, sass

Bom dia! Estou a fazer alguns teste com a função do sass ela não me retorna nada.
Achei que era algo que eu estava digitando errado, ou algo do tipo. Fui copiei a função exata deste site [aqui](http://thesassway.com/advanced/pure-sass-functions) e ainda continua o erro.
A função é está aqui

```
        @function cp($target, $container) {
      @return calc-percent($target, $container);
    }
.my-module {
  width: calc-percent(650px, 1000px);
}
```

Já limpei cache do navegador, já tentei em ferramentas online...Enfim, o que poderia fazer ?

Comment: Você está declarando a função ```calc-percent```? Porque no link a função cp é só um nome menor pra calc-percent, que é declarada antes de cp.

Answer (score 1):

Você não chamou a função. Acredito que o correto seria:

```
.my-module {
   width: cp(650px, 1000px);
}
```

Comment: Fiz a chamada assim, e não alterou em nada.

Answer (score 0):

O link que você colocou na pergunta mostra duas funções. Uma é a calc-percent e a outra é a cp que é só um nome menor pra função já declarada.

```
@function calc-percent($target, $container) {
  @return ($target / $container) * 100%;
}

@function cp($target, $container) {
  @return calc-percent($target, $container);
}

.my-module {
  width: cp(650px, 1000px);
}
```

Ela funciona perfeitamente, possivelmente você não declarou a função calc-percent. Abstraindo ela fica até mais simples o código.

```
@function cp($target, $container) {
  @return ($target / $container) * 100%;
}

.my-module {
  width: cp(650px, 1000px);
}
```

Que resulta no seguinte CSS:

```
.my-module {
  width: 65%;
}
```